# Excel Dynamic OFFSET Function

Tags: excel, offset

This formula works OFFSET(RevFull!$B$261,ROWS($C$5:C5),COLUMNS($D$3:D3))
I'm trying to make the "RevFull!$B$261" dynamic with this ="RevFull!"&ADDRESS(MATCH($C$2,RevFull!$B$1:$B$298,0),2)
Alone this equation yields "RevFull!$B$261"

When I put the two together i.e. OFFSET("RevFull!"&ADDRESS(MATCH($C$2,RevFull!$B$1:$B$298,0),2) ,ROWS($C$5:C5),COLUMNS($D$3:D3)) Excel will not calculate.

I've tried to use the indirect function as well to accomplish this i.e

OFFSET(INDIRECT("RevFull!")&ADDRESS(MATCH($C$2,RevFull!$B$1:$B$298,0),2) ,ROWS($C$5:C5),COLUMNS($D$3:D3))

This also does not calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=INDEX(RevFull!$B:$ZZ,MATCH($C$2,RevFull!$B$1:$B$298,0)+ROWS($C$5:C5),COLUMNS($D$3:D3))
```

And avoid the volatile offset, indirect, and address functions.